# pass a function with several arguments and some constants down a dataframe column, and output a new column for each term in the vector

Tags: r, function, loops, apply

I am trying to use a column in my df, the df is called combo, as an argument 'h' in my function. As well as a vector 'v'. The df is:

- 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  2 variables:

  - $ fake : num  2.24e-05 2.40e-05 2.69e-05 2.87e-05 3.14e-05 ...
  - $ funny: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

The vector is `ve`: 
-str(ve)
- num [1:6] 1.37 2.4 2.23 3.2 2.9 3.22

The Function is:

```
f<-function(h, v){
  m_k<- (Density*h)/(Cd*v)
  y<- m_k*(v*sin(a)+(m_k*g))
  return (y)
}
```

where `Density` and `Cd` are constants. 
I get the following error when I run `f(combo$fake, ve)`

> Warning messages:
>
> > 1: In (Density * h)/(Cd * v) :
> >
> > > longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

and I get that they are not the same length. But what I would like is for R to apply the function using the first term of `ve` for each term in `combo$fake` , producing one column for that first `ve` and then repeat with the 2nd term in `ve`so that in the end I have 6 columns and 10 rows of results given by the function.

I have tried using the apply functions, and a for loop, as well as referring to the arguments explicitly as with `combo$fake`, but I want to avoid hardcoding the function (otherwise I wouldnt use a function). This is just a sample, my real dataset is much bigger.

Here  are some examples of what I ve tried and a tibble of the dataframe.

```
combo$fake $funny
        <dbl>  <int>
 1  0.0000224      1
 2  0.000024       2
 3  0.0000269      3
 4  0.0000287      4
 5  0.0000314      5
 6  0.0000324      6
```

```
y<-    for (i in seq_len(ve))  {
  for(j in seq_along(combo$fake))

    f(combo$fake, ve)
}
```

```
y<- mapply(f, ve, combo$fake)
```

I've tried reading other similar questions on stackoverflow, but I just cannot get it to work :-( . Needless to say, I am very new in R, please help and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mapply` takes the first element of each argument and puts it into your function, then proceeds with the second element of each argument and so on. You can simply get your arguments into the shape needed by repeating its elements, such that element one of `ve` is combined with each element of `df$fake` before using the next value of `ve`. So essentially using `rep` with its arguments `times` and `each`.

If I understand your question correctly, you can use something like this:

```
# your function and its constants
f<-function(h, v){
  Density <- 10
  Cd <- 10
  a <- 10
  g <- 10
  m_k<- (Density*h)/(Cd*v)
  y<- m_k*(v*sin(a)+(m_k*g))
  return (y)
}

# some dataframe and vector
df <- data.frame(fake = 1:10)
ve <- 20:25

# call mapply by repeating df$fake by the length of vector
# and repeat each element in the vector by the number of elements in df$fake
results <- mapply(f, rep(df$fake, times = length(ve)),
                     rep(ve, each = length(df$fake)))

# reshape the output
matrix(results, nrow=length(df$fake), ncol=length(ve))
```